# How select all Data Categories with apex

Tags: apex, soql, knowledge, data-category

How can I select all categories types in salesforce with apex?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean select them? Do you mean within the search feature in your screenshot or you just want to access them programatically?

Comment: I can receive all categories in visualforce using this tag:

<select name="category" id="categories">
<knowledge:categoryList categoryVar="category" categoryGroup="Test_group" rootCategory="All" level="-1">
<option value="{!category.name}">{!category.label}</option>
</knowledge:categoryList>
</select>

Can I fetch the same in apex?

Answer (score 0):

You can use describes to get the information you need:

```
List<DescribeDataCategoryGroupResult> describes = Schema.describeDataCategoryGroups(
    new List<String> { 'KnowledgeArticleVersion' }
);
for (DescribeDataCategoryGroupResult describe : describes)
{
    system.debug(category.getName());
    system.debug(category.getLabel());
    system.debug(category.getDescription());
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but I fetched:

System.NoAccessException: Entity is not org-accessible